# motivation behind using Bochner spaces in study of time dependent parabolic problems

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, bochner-spaces

I am studying the theory of parabolic partial differential equation of type
$u_t-\Delta u=f$. Now while defining the weak formulation we have used the Bochner spaces $L^2(0,T;H_0^1(\Omega))$. Can anyone explain why we consider these vector valued spaces to study parabolic equations. Can't we take functions of $(x,t)$ directly?

Comment: If you test the equation with the solution, then you get a-priori estimates in precisely these norms. So these spaces play the same role as the space $H^1$ for the elliptic pde.

Comment: Just from a practical standpoint, this allows us to explicitly determine the regularity of the solution in $t$ vs. $x$. For example, if we knew the function was $H^2$ in $x$ but $H^1$ in $t$, that becomes a mess very quickly when considering everything in the joint space.